# Can't save checkmarks in a PDF file

Tags: macos, pdf, preview.app

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the rationale behind Fillable PDF's not being able to be saved?](https://superuser.com/questions/122847/whats-the-rationale-behind-fillable-pdfs-not-being-able-to-be-saved)
>   [Save data typed into PDF Form](https://superuser.com/questions/130295/save-data-typed-into-pdf-form)

I was sent a PDF form with some input check boxes. When I click on the empty check boxes they show a check mark inside of them, but when I save the document, close it, and reopen it then my check marks are lost..  So what do I need to do in order to save my changes so that I can return this PDF file?

Comment: Have you tried printing to a PDF document?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save data typed into PDF Form](http://superuser.com/questions/130295/save-data-typed-into-pdf-form) also see [What's the rationale behind Fillable PDF's not being able to be saved?](http://superuser.com/questions/122847/whats-the-rationale-behind-fillable-pdfs-not-being-able-to-be-saved)